# How to return an array of data attributes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Please excuse my poor javascript knowledge.

I'm trying to return an array of ID values, e.g. [1,2,4], from DOM elements that are marked 'selected'.

```
<tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '1'></tr>
<tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '2'></tr>
<tr data-selected = 'false' data-id = '3'></tr>
<tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '4'></tr>
```

My attempt at creating a coffeescript function for this

```
elems = $("tr[data-selected ='true']").data("id")    
alert( elems )
```

This appears to only return the data-id value of the last element.

How do I create an array of all ID values?

Comment: btw question doesn't have jquery tagged but looking at the snippet i assume it is jquery only...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('tr[data-selected="true"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgZ4j/)**

When you use attr/data on a selector that returns multiple items, it will give you the result from only the first matched element. So using [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) get the specific dat attrib value and convert to an array from jquery object collection.

Reason for that lies in the way `.attr/data` is implemented.

```
// Gets
bulk ?
    fn.call( elems ) :
    length ? fn( elems[0], key ) : emptyGet; //<-- snippet from jquery just considers the first element.
```

Comment: thanks, just what I was looking for. And a very useful explanation too

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use also `.each` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ids = [];
  elems = $("tr[data-selected=true]").each(function(){
   ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  });
console.log(ids);
})

<tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '1'></tr>
<tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '2'></tr>
<tr data-selected = 'false' data-id = '3'></tr>
```

http://jsbin.com/iqEYAPI/1/edit

Comment: `each` should never be used to turn one collection into another collection; that's what `map` is for.